# Why the script is not running on all input elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this script to hide the default value of input elements on my page:

```
<script>

var active_color = '#000'; // Colour of user provided text
var inactive_color = '#ccc'; // Colour of default text


window.onload = formDefaultValues;

function formDefaultValues() {
  var fields = getElementsByClassName(document, "input", "default-value");
  if (!fields) {
    return;
  }
  var default_values = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i].style.color = inactive_color;
    if (!default_values[fields[i].id]) {
      default_values[fields[i].id] = fields[i].value;
    }
    fields[i].onfocus = function() { 
      if (this.value == default_values[this.id]) {
        this.value = '';
        this.style.color = active_color;
      }
      this.onblur = function() {
        if (this.value == '') {
          this.style.color = inactive_color;
          this.value = default_values[this.id];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



function getElementsByClassName(oElm, strTagName, strClassName){
  var arrElements = (strTagName == "*" && oElm.all)? oElm.all : oElm.getElementsByTagName(strTagName);
  var arrReturnElements = new Array();
  strClassName = strClassName.replace(/\-/g, "\\-");
  var oRegExp = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + strClassName + "(\\s|$)");
  var oElement;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrElements.length; i++) {
    oElement = arrElements[i];
    if (oRegExp.test(oElement.className)) {
      arrReturnElements.push(oElement);
    }
  }
  return (arrReturnElements);
}
</script>
```

I use this code to loop on input elements that have the class "default-value" and fire the action on them. It's really working on some elements but not others? What might be going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you setup a working/non-working example at http://jsfiddle.com? Do all your elements have unique id attributes?

Comment: And please be more specific about what doesn't work. How does it fail? Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: Does `getElementsByClassName` work like that? Should you use `document.getElementsByClassName("default-value")`? That just doesn't filter the input elements so be sure to check that you only use that class on inputs.

Comment: I mean, when I click on some inputs, their default values disappear, but some other elements just still have their default values their.. All of them have the same class, only one if them has it's unique id

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me..

```
<html>
<script>
    function ViewAllElements() {
        var fe = document.forms['myForm'].elements;
        alert(fe.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < fe.length; i++)
        {
            alert(fe[i].value);
        }

        var ebc = getElementsByClassName(document, "input", "fieldA");
        alert(ebc.length);
        for(var j = 0; j < ebc.length; j++)
        {
            alert(ebc[j].value);
        }
    }

    function getElementsByClassName(oElm, strTagName, strClassName){
      var arrElements = (strTagName == "*" && oElm.all)? oElm.all : oElm.getElementsByTagName(strTagName);
      var arrReturnElements = new Array();
      strClassName = strClassName.replace(/\-/g, "\\-");
      var oRegExp = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + strClassName + "(\\s|$)");
      var oElement;
      for (var i = 0; i < arrElements.length; i++) {
        oElement = arrElements[i];
        if (oRegExp.test(oElement.className)) {
          arrReturnElements.push(oElement);
        }
      }
      return (arrReturnElements);
    }

</script>

<body>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <input class="fieldA" id="field1" name="field1" value="field1value">
    <input class="fieldA" id="field2" name="field2" value="field2value">
    <input class="fieldA" id="field3" name="field3" value="field3value">
    <input class="fieldB" id="field4" name="field4" value="field4value">
    <input class="fieldB" id="field5" name="field5" value="field5value">
    <input class="fieldB" id="field6" name="field6" value="field6value">
    <input type="button" onClick="ViewAllElements();" value="View">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```